# Forbid conversions to parent, but expose publicly parent's interface (design issue)

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17

I'm not sure how to implement (express in C++) following problem in the most elegant way. Let's say that we have a library providing class `PerfectCounter` with rich non-virtual interface. I want to implement class `DisturbedCounter` that inherit from `PerfectCounter`. The new class should expose the same interface as its' parent and e.g. allow some operators (`<`, `>`, =`=`, etc.) to be called for pairs of instances of both classes. Moreover, I want to disallow conversions between two classes (in both ways).

`DisturbedCounter` can inherit privately from `PerfectCounter`. It will block conversions from `DisturbedCounter` to `PerfectCounter`. However, I'll have to explicitly re-declare 99% of `PerfectCounter` API as "public" in `DisturbedCounter`. It means lot of writing and maintenance in future.

Is there any better way to solve this problem?

I can use C++17.

Comment: If those functions are virtual, why do you not want the conversion to parent? If they are not virtual, overriding them seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @SergeyA `PerfectCounter` has non-virtual interface, I failed to mention it before.

Comment: Excellent question, alas, without an answer in today's C++. We would like to have `using A::* except blargh;` Maybe one day.

Comment: @n.m. Indeed that's something I'm looking for. I was shyly hoping that there's a neat C++1* construction solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could let DisturbedCounter inherit privately from PerfectCounter. Then conversions between them will not be allowed (since DisturbedCounter is not a PerfectCounter in that case, it's merely implemented *in terms of* one).

Then you can use `using` directives to publicly expose the parts of PerfectCounters interface that you want publicly available in DisturbedCounter and add in implementations of whatever comparison operators you want.

There are certainly other ways to go about it, but that's at least one for you to consider.

Comment: This is the approach I described in second paragraph (maybe I wasn't clear enough). It's quite tedious solution, because I'll have to use `using` for each method from PerfectCounter.

Comment: @Goofy I see that now (when re-reading) - I guess I suck at reading. Anyway; yes, tedious, but still the most straightforward way *I* can think of to solve this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you need since DisturbedCounter doesn't inherit from PerfectCounter. It's using [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to avoid conversions, and it should allow you to only do the implementation of each method once (except for those that really should be different) and you don't need `using` from a base class. I'm not good with templates so this will probably be ripped apart by someone but o.t.o.h., if it's not, it may give you some idea and it could be something to build on. A lot of boilerplate is missing.

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct Common {
protected:
    double m_count;

public:
    Common() : m_count(0) {}
    Common& operator=(const Common& rhs) {
        m_count = rhs.m_count;
        return *this;
    }

    operator double () const { return m_count; }
    double get() const { return m_count; }
};

// type specific implementation
struct PerfectCounter : Common<PerfectCounter> {
    void count() {
        m_count += 10.0;
    }
};

// type specific implementation
struct DisturbedCounter : Common<DisturbedCounter> {
    void count() {
        m_count += 9.9;
    }
};

int main() {
    PerfectCounter a;
    a.count();
    DisturbedCounter b;
    b.count();

    //a = b; // error
    //b = a; // error

    if( a>b ) std::cout << "a>b\n";

    std::cout << a << " " << b << "\n";
}
```

Output

```
a>b
10 9.9
```